# How to test whether credentials are valid?

Tags: libgit2

I could not find in the docs the canonical way to check whether given credentials can be used to clone given repository. There is an [issue](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go/issues/246) that suggests that one way may be to check whether git_cred_acquire_cb() is called more than once. Can somebody confirm this or point out another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the suggested way.  If your credential callback is called a second time, then the first credentials that you provided were not accepted.  This pattern is primarily useful for UI applications (popping up a modal username/password dialog).

You can use the callback data to count the number of times you were called.

I realize that this may be imperfect, especially if you're binding libgit2 in another language.  Setting up a data struct on the heap and managing its lifecycle is not always trivial.

You *may* also be able to just provide credentials and wait for a `GIT_EAUTH` return code.  In theory, the various transport mechanisms should give up after several authentication failures no matter what.  However, we found at least one bug in the 0.27 releases that would loop forever.  Hence the suggestion.